# Access an object within a method created in another Class

Tags: javascript, class

I'm currently learning JavaScript and am having issues.
I have two classes that's for two different "Screens" or pages, let's call them `NewActivityScreen` and `CalendarScreen`. On the `NewActivityScreen` I have a form with a submit button that saves the inputs into my `newActivity` object inside the submitButton function in the `NewActivityScreen` Class.

```
submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  //Prevents the page from loading after submit button is pressed.
  e.preventDefault();

  let newActivity = {
    name: document.getElementsByName('activity-input')[0].value,
    date: document.getElementsByName('date-input')[0].value
  }

  document.getElementById('activity-form').reset();

  this.displayActivity(newActivity);
});
```

When it does this I'd like to append it to the `DisplayScreen` Class so when I press the nav-link to create the new `DisplayScreen` I'd like the results to show on this screen. Kind of like this:

```
displayActivity(activity) {
    const activityContainer = document.createElement('div')
    activityContainer.setAttribute('class', 'activity-container')
    const activityName = document.createElement('h4')
    const activityDate = document.createElement('h4')
    activityName.textContent = 'Activity: ' + activity.name;
    activityDate.textContent = 'Date: ' + activity.date;

    document.getElementById('main-content').appendChild(activityContainer)
    activityContainer.appendChild(activityName);
    activityContainer.appendChild(activityDate);
}
```

Now the problem with this is as soon as I press the submit button on the `NewActivityScreen` it appends on the `CalendarScreen`, which my code says it should. Is there a way to append it to the `CalendarScreen` without having two different HTML `section` for the pages?

In short: I'd like it so when I press the submit button the `displayActivity` function gets appended into the CalendarScreen if possible.

For reference: My code looks like this https://pastebin.com/WymQ5H12

Comment: Where is the `DisplayScreen` created? You talk about "*in another class*", but I don't see any `class`es in your code.

Comment: It is the ```CalendarScreen``` Class. Currently I have no code there. But am trying to figure out how to make it so my ```displayActivity``` method gets appended into the ```CalendarScreen```

Comment: @Bergi Corrected.